# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#09022 relayoutBoundary

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

*The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#09022 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'*

*The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.*

Hello everyone, this has already been applied before, everything worked, but now I'm getting an error that my list gets an unlimited height. What is the problem?

In Flowers.shoppingBasket - an array consisting of words (pieces 5 +-)

`Flowers.shoppingBasket = await SharedPreferencesUtil.getData<StringList>("header");`

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      width: 500,
                      height: 650,
                      child: 
ListView.builder(
  controller: controller,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  itemCount: Flowers.shoppingBasket!.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index < Flowers.shoppingBasket!.length)  {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black))
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Text(' ${Flowers.shoppingBasket?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),

      );

    } else {
   ............
     
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you include more about parent widget of listView

Comment: @YeasinSheikh ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` widget.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
```

I will recommend to check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI&vl=en)

Comment: It did not help

Comment: Can you include an error layout image

Comment: Also try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app, your approach is ok .

Comment: Sorry, I messed something up and this is the solution!

Comment: Also try to avoid using `shrinkWrap: true,` whenever possible , [check more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0)

Answer (score 3):

You missed to add shrinkwrap in listview

```dart
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
)
```

Comment: My answer is same as yours so I haven't added. @Daniil this is the solution of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your Listview.builder in Expanded widget to let listview take the all space.